# Need to understand ViewState property code

Tags: c#, viewstate

I couldn't understand the meaning of this code. Why we use viewstate and which purpose i need to use viewstate here. i am new to this area. Please help me to understand each line of code.

```
   public int ParentPageVSValue
  {
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["_ParentPageVSValue"] != null)
            return int.Parse(ViewState["_ParentPageVSValue"].ToString());
        else
            return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["_ParentPageVSValue"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: ViewState is ASP.Net feature to preserve data between postbacks, read more about state management here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

Comment: @user3510330 Check my answer and tell me if something is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

> View state's purpose in life is simple: it's there to persist state
>   across postbacks. (For an ASP.NET Web page, its state is the property
>   values of the controls that make up its control hierarchy.)

I advice you to read the whole article [Understanding ASP.NET View State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

**The ViewState Property**

> Each control is responsible for storing its own state, which is
>   accomplished by adding its changed state to its ViewState property.
>   The ViewState property is defined in the System.Web.UI.Control class,
>   meaning that all ASP.NET server controls have this property available.
>   If you
>   examine the simple properties of any ASP.NET server control you'll see
>   that the properties read and write directly to the view state. For example, consider the HyperLink Web
>   control's NavigateUrl property. The code for this property looks like
>   so:

```
public string NavigateUrl
{
    get
    {
       string text = (string) ViewState["NavigateUrl"];
       if (text != null)
          return text;
       else
          return string.Empty;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["NavigateUrl"] = value;
    }
}
```

How view state is looking, it is added as hidden field with name `__VIEWSTATE` in the html of your page:
[image: View State]

How the decoded view state is looking:

[image: View State decoded]

So in your case, you create a property which save a int value in the view state(hidden field in the html). After that you can retrieve it from the same hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

View state can stores the values that have to be retained during postback.

View state provides state information for a specific ASP.NET page. If you need to use information on more than one page, or if you need the information to persist across visits to the Web site.

Suggest you to go through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) post for more information.